# I'm trying to get a separate outcome in this code but it constantly display both. I've tried "if statement" but it doesn't help. Help me plz

Tags: python-3.x

```
print('Welcome to Python Times Table')
wrong_answer = ''
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input('What number do you want to multiply by: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter Integer Only")
        continue
    else:
        for n in range (11):
            res = number * n
            print(f'{number} * {n} = ?') 
            while True: 
                try:
                    answer = int(input("Your Answer: "))
                except ValueError:
                    print('Only Integer Allowed.')
                else: 
                    if number * n != answer:
                        print("Incorrect!")
                        print(f'{number} * {n} = ?')
                        wrong_answer += f'{number} * {n} = {res} -> Your Answer:{answer}\n'
                        continue
                    elif number * n == answer:
                        print('Correct')
                        break 
    print("These are the answer you missed!")
    print(wrong_answer)
    
    print('Congratulation! ALL answer are correct!')
```

Comment: "code only" questions are ignored, why `elif` if the `if` contains a `!=`, the case that the answer is _maybe_ correct does not exist

Answer (score 0):

```py
if number * n != number:
    print("\nThese are the answer you missed!\n")
    print(wrong_answer)
else:
    print('Congratulation! ALL answer are correct!')

choice = int(input("Learn another table? 1 for YES, 2 for NO: "))
if choice == 1:
    choice == True
    wrong_answer = ''
else:
    print('Bye Bye')
    break
```

I cleared the string once I wanted to redo the timetable!